# How do I Insert data from text table (using MultiDelimitSerDe) to Avro Table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql, hiveql

I noticed that I can use an insert into statement from text table to avro table when not using the MultiDelimitSerDe. It also works with ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," i.e. a single character.

I create 2 tables - 1 text table and 1 avro table:

> CREATE TABLE example1 ( example STRING, example2 STRING, example3
>   STRING ) ROW FORMAT SERDE
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe' WITH
>   SERDEPROPERTIES ("field.delim"="**") STORED AS TEXTFILE  ;
>
> CREATE TABLE example2 ( example STRING,  example2 STRING,  example3
>   STRING ) STORED AS AVRO;

I then load data into example1 table (file delimited by "**")i.e.

> LOAD DATA INPATH 'HDFS-path' INTO TABLE example1;

example1 now has data inside it. I want to insert the data from example1 to example2.

> INSERT INTO TABLE example2 SELECT * from example1;

This however, gives a "return code 2" error. I have no idea why I am unable to insert the data using the MultiDelimitSerDe but I am able to do this with "ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY". But, I need to use a multi-delimiter.

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the required JAR file?

'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe' - Make sure you have the required JAR file for this (hive_contrib.jar).